Next.Js build error "Export encountered errors on following paths:" but doesn't say which path
Whenever I try to run "npm run build" on my project I get the following error:

Export encountered errors on following paths:
/page: /

I know that it technically has to do with the directories but in my case it does not say which one is the problem, only says " / ".
I'm very new to this and have no idea how to fix it, my project doesn't have any kind of server sided stuff, it's all going to be static hosting.
I simply tried to run "npm run build" but always run into said error, this is how my next.config.mjs looks like:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    }
};

export default nextConfig;


Do you see any errors when running project in dev? Try looking in console also in browser inspect. Basically, error is there at root page so it is not specifying any particular path.

Kindly ask queries as comment. Not as answer
